# REST API get by author differences by platform

Tags: rest, filter, query, cross-platform

I find that when I want to retrieve custom list items by author (in this case, by the current user) I need to use a different query whether using SP2013 on premise or O365.  I tried creating the same custom list on both platforms.

For on-premise, this query works:

```
var q = "?$select=Author/Id,*&$expand=Author&$filter=(Author/Id eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId + ")";
```

but, for O365, I need to use this query:

```
var q = "?$filter=(AuthorId eq " + _spPageContextInfo.userId + ")";
```

Neither query works for me on the other platform.

Anyone have the same experience? I've seen posts where people assert one or the other form works and replies saying that that form doesn't work... but the posters and responders generally don't say what environment they are working in.  Could some other setting be changing how the query/filter works?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the filter expression:

```
$filter=(AuthorId eq <UserId>)
```

does return the error in SharePoint *on-premise*:

> Column 'AuthorId' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another
>   user

The list of expressions that are supported in SharePoint Online/on-premise:

- `$filter=(Author eq <UserId>)`
- `?$select=Author/Id,*&$expand=Author&$filter=(Author/Id eq <UserId>)`